# Is it possible to Install Anaconda while keeping preinstalled Python and PyCharm intact?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have installed Python 3.8 an Pycharm. Now I would like to install Anaconda which has python 3.7. Can I keep my Python and Pycharm and install Anaconda? Will they not interfere?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: @Z4-tier not at all. I have both conda and multiple python versions on my linux desktop. No problems whatsoever

Comment: I have already installed anaconda and Pycharm with different python versions. make sure after installations keep all are in up to date.

Comment: The Anaconda FAQ has a section called [Installing Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda) which covers this exact thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this will not interfere as Anaconda will be installed in a virtual environment. So no worries you can keep multiple version at any point of time.